# Hopefield contribution matrix pattern recognition

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix, neural-network

I'm reading the book:

> Introduction to Neural Networks for C# Second Edition by Jeff Heaton

In particular the chapter about Hopefield network. He explains how to calculate the contribution matrix given a boolean array as pattern.

For exaple given the following pattern `0101`, the corresponding contribution matrix (of weights) is:

```
0  -1  1  -1
-1  0 -1  1
1  -1  0  -1
-1  1 -1  0
```

The process of recognize the pattern follow this rule:

> We must now compare those weights with the input pattern of 0101. We
>   will sum only the weights corresponding to the positions that contain
>   a 1 in the input pattern. The results of the activation of each neuron
>   are shown below.
>
> N1 = -1 + -1 = -2
>   N2 = 0 + 1 = 1
>   N3 = -1 + -1 = -2
>   N4 = 1 + 0 = 1
>
> These values are meaningless without an activation function. The
>   activation function used for a Hopfield network is any value greater
>   than zero, so the following neurons will fire.
>
> N1 activation result is –2; will not fire (0)
>   N2 activation result is 1; will fire (1)
>   N3 activation result is –2; will not fire(0)
>
> N4 activation result is 1; will fire (1)
>
> As you can see, we assign a binary value of 1 to all neurons that
>   fired, and a binary value of 0 to all neurons that did not fire. The
>   final binary output from the Hopfield network will be 0101. This is
>   the same as the input pattern.

Moreover he said:

> If we also want to recognize 1001, then we would calculate both
>   contribution matrixes and add the results to create the connection
>   weight matrix

So I calculate the second contribution matrix:

```
0  -1  -1  1
-1  0  1  -1
-1  1  0  -1
1  -1 -1  0
```

And add the two matrixes:

```
0 -2 0 0
-2 0 0 0
0 0 0 -2
0 0 -2 0
```

And obviously (following the previous rule) this last matrix cannot recognize any of the previous patterns. How is it possible? Where is the error?

**EDIT**: (Added the example provided by the author)

Considering the [example](http://www.heatonresearch.com/online/introduction-neural-networks-cs-edition-2/chapter-3/page4.html) provided, the two patterns are:

`1100` -> `[1 1 -1 -1]`

```
0   1   -1  -1
1   0   -1  -1
-1  -1  0   1
-1  -1  1   0
```

`1000` -> `[1 -1 -1 -1]`

```
0   -1  -1  -1
-1  0   1   1
-1  1   0   1
-1  1   1   0
```

Addition:

```
0   0   -2  -2
0   0   0   0
-2  0   0   2
-2  0   2   0
```

Multiply by `[1 1 -1 -1]`:

```
4   0   -4  -4
```

Multiply by `[1 -1 -1 -1]`:

```
4   0   -4  -4
```

In both cases the pattern recognized is `1000` (`1100` is missing). Thus, there is something not working here.

Comment: Here the full chapter: http://www.heatonresearch.com/online/introduction-neural-networks-cs-edition-2/chapter-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This source doesn't look very good. For example it uses the term "inverse" instead of "transpose". Also the algorithm for recalling patterns is described incorrectly. Fortunately if you look at their implementation it seems to work fine (although it's also a low quality code).

The difference is that when you present a vector to recall a pattern for, you should also convert it to bipolar form and then calculate the dot product with each column of the weight matrix. So, in your example when you'll present the vector `1001` you calculate:

```
                  |0  -2  0  0|
[1 -1 -1 1]   *   |-2  0  0  0|   = [2 -2 -2 2]
                  |0   0  0 -2|   
                  |0   0 -2  0|
```

After applying the threshold function it yields the correct result: `1001`. For the second vector, `0101`:

```
                 |0  -2  0  0|
[-1 1 -1 1]   *  |-2  0  0  0|    = [-2 2 -2 2]
                 |0   0  0 -2|   
                 |0   0 -2  0|
```

which also gives correct result: `0101`.

**EDIT**:

In your second example you seem to have reached the limit of Hopfield network capabilities. First of all, the patterns you present differ with only one bit, which makes them hard to tell apart. This, combined with the fact that Hopfield Network's capacity is said to be something around `0.138 * n` ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network#Capacity)), `n` being the number of neurons seems to explain the problem.

Other sources, like [this one](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~rosen/161/NeuralNotes/NeuralNotes.html) (Chapter 6) provide theoretical bound of `n/2 * log(n)` - for "almost all patterns" to be retrieved without errors. In this link you can also find other learning rules. And you can find another simple example [here](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~rosen/161/notes/hopfield.html).

Comment: Ok, now it seems to have sense, but considering my edit (to the question), even your solution doesn't work. Can you say why?

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, do you think the code is of a low quality for the implementation or even for the algorithm? In the latter, do you have any source for a different implementation?

Comment: @gliderkite I was just referring to the quality of the code itself (one small example: stupid `bipolar2double` function name - this function doesn't convert "bipolar to double", it converts boolean to bipolar stored in double). As for any existing implementations I think you know more than me, as I didn't even know about the one you've provided link to :)